# How do I make a winform minimize animation

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I add an animation to Form's Minimize?

Here's an example:  https://i.gyazo.com/fddb5bf0ce748ae69320ae08e1986ac3.mp4

I am using Winforms C#

Comment: Take a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: The question seems understandable enough to me

Comment: @CaptainKenpachi, yes but it should show an attempt to solve the problem. Currently we don't know why the OP is having issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDITED:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TestMinimize
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.Timer t = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        System.Windows.Forms.Timer t1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        bool Minimized;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            t.Interval = 2; // specify interval time as you want
            t.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
            this.SizeChanged += new EventHandler(this_SizeChanged);
            t1.Interval = 1;
            t1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
            t1.Start();
        }

        private void this_SizeChanged(object source, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Normal)
            {
                Minimized = false;
            }
        }

        private void timer_Tick(object source, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Height = this.Height-8;
            if (this.Height == 39)
            {
                t.Stop();
                t.Enabled = false;
                this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
                Minimized = true;
            }
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object source, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(Minimized==false && t.Enabled == false)
            {
                this.Height = 221;
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            t.Start();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214798/discussion-on-answer-by-d-j-how-do-i-make-a-winform-minimize-animation).